# Dictionary of functions with returning value C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I'm having trouble creating dictionary of functions. The issue I'm running against is how to return value from called method.

I tried something like this but it's not working since I get error about returning value from anonymous function. I don't know how to properly invoke lambda since the examples I've seen have no arguments, while I have both input parameters and return value.

```
private static Dictionary<string, Action<String, String>> dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Action<String, String>>()
{
      {"key",
          (arg1, arg2) => {
              Class instance= new Class();
              return instance.MyFunction(arg1, arg2);)
      }
}
```

And I want to call it as

```
 dictionary["key"]("abc", "123");
```

I know making MyFunction static would be simpler but `Class` is implementing an interface and I'm working on C# 7.3

Comment: You can't return from `void` method and also have an extra bracket. What is the signature of `MyFunction`?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm asking how I can create dictionary with functions that will have return type

Comment: You should use `Func<string, string,string>` for that

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Func` , not `Action`, since `Action` cannot return a value. The last Type argument to `Func` is the return type.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, Func<String, String, String>> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<String, String, String>>()
        {
            {
                "key",
                (arg1, arg2) =>
                {
                    Class instance = new Class();
                    return instance.MyFunction(arg1, arg2);
                }
            }
        };
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Func` delegate instead of `Action`, since it'll return a value (unlike `Action`) of type specified by last type argument. Assuming that `MyFunction` returns `string`, you can declare it like

```cs
private static Dictionary<string, Func<string, string,string>> dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<string, string, string>>
    {
        {
            "key",
            (arg1, arg2) =>
            {
                var instance = new Class();
                return instance.MyFunction(arg1, arg2);
            }
        }
    };
```

And invoke like

```cs
var result = dictionary["key"]("abc", "123");
```

You also should fix a typo with an extra bracket in your code.